# Editing conditional formatting formulas

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need to generate VBA code to edit existing formulas used for conditional formatting.

If I currently have:

[image]

I need VBA to change it to:

[image]

What I have tried so far:

```
FormString = "=IFERROR(FIND(""that"",A1),FALSE)"
For Each fc In FormulaSheet.UsedRange.FormatConditions
    If TypeName(fc) = "FormulaString" Then
        fc.Formula1 = FormString 
    End If
Next fc
```

The above code runs, but doesn't change anything.

I know how to create a new condition with a formula (using `Range("A1").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=FormString`)

But once it's created, I can't seem to be able to change the formula with VBA.

My problem is I get worksheets with a lot of conditions and need to edit the formulas, but not touch anything else. I could store all the parameters, delete the conditions and recreate them with new formulas but that seems a very inefficient way to go about it

Comment: Don't you need the "=" in the FormString?

Comment: You are right, but that is not the problem :(  that was a typo -- edited the question

Comment: check out the [.modify method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.modify)

Comment: @Cyril - Looks like what I was looking for -- thanks!

Comment: FYI: the IFERROR is not needed.  Errors in formulas are considered FALSE by conditional Formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I have a VBA function that make a "SumIf" based on cell color.
You may adapt it to your necessities.
Have fun:

```
Function SOMACOR(Referência As Range, Matriz As Range, Fonte As Boolean)

Application.Volatile

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rCor As Long
Dim rResult As Variant

    If Fonte = False Then
        rCor = Referência.Interior.ColorIndex

        For Each rCell In Matriz
            If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = rCor Then
                rResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, rResult)
            End If
        Next rCell
    Else
        rCor = Referência.Font.ColorIndex

        For Each rCell In Matriz
            If rCell.Font.ColorIndex = rCor Then
                rResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, rResult)
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If

    SOMACOR = rResult

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't utilize Conditional Formatting which is the OP's request.